# Where can I find agents for a relatively new player?

Tags: eve-online

I'm done with the main "tutorial" agents and I did a couple of other agent missions after that. Now I can't find any more. I'm in Cistuvaert and I've searched around in the solar systems around that. Are these agent missions a big part of the game or should I figure out what I actually want to do. I want one of the more casual things to do like mining. I quite enjoy scanning actually now that I think of it. Is that a good choice for a newer player?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Agent Finder](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Agent_Finder) to find suitable agents for mission running. There is an icon for that in the station services sidebar when you are docked. It allows you to filter according to agent level, agent type, faction and corporation. You'll have to use level 1 agents until you have enough standing with the faction or corporation of the agent to be able to use the higher level agents.

Agents give out missions, and those missions are one of the major income sources for players. But you don't have to do them, you can earn your ISK in many other ways and e.g. PvP without flying a single mission, if you don't want to. I would recommend to do some missions in the beginning to get a feel for the controls and some combat basics, though PvE combat is very, very different from PvP.

There are lots of things you can do in EVE, I would recommend to just try out a few things. You can scan as a pretty new character, the rewards are pretty random so it might not be a reliable income source early on.